# Routing "paths" through a rectangular array

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph, puzzle

I'm trying to create my own implementation of a puzzle game.

To create my game board, I need to traverse each square in my array once and only once.
The traversal needs to be linked to an adjacent neighbor (horizontal, vertical or diagonal).

I'm using an array structure of the form:

```
board[n,m] = byte
Each bit of the byte represents a direction 0..7 and exactly 2 bits are always set
Directions are numbered clockwise
0 1 2 
7 . 3
6 5 4 
Board[0,0] must have some combination of bits 3,4,5 set
```

My current approach for constructing a random path is:

```
 Start at a random position
 While (Squares remain)
    if no directions from this square are valid, step backwards
    Pick random direction from those remaining in bitfield for this square       
    Erase the direction to this square from those not picked
    Move to the next square
```

This algorithm takes far too long on some medium sized grids, because earlier choices remove areas from consideration.

What I'd like to have is a function that takes an index into every possible path, and returns with the array filled in for that path.   This would let me provide a 'seed' value to return to this particular board.

Other suggestions are welcome..

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to construct a path in a grid such that each element is visited exactly once?

Comment: Yes.  Each element visited exactly once, and there are no gaps.

Comment: I suspect you've stumbled onto a difficult problem.  The only advice I can give is to try to detect and avoid situations where you block regions.  If you were doing this by hand, you'd instinctively 'stick' to existing filled regions to avoid creating such blocked areas.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you want to construct a [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path): A path that visits each node of a graph exactly once.

In general, even if you only want to test whether a graph contains a Hamiltonian path, that's already NP-complete. In this case, it's obvious that the graph contains at least one Hamiltonian path, and the graph has a nice regular structure -- but enumerating all Hamiltonian paths still seems to be a difficult problem.

The [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) on the Hamiltonian path problem has a randomized algorithm for finding a Hamiltonian path that is claimed to be "fast on most graphs". It's different from your algorithm in that it swaps around a whole branch of the path instead of backtracking by just one node. This more "aggressive" strategy might be faster -- try it and see.

You could let your users enter the seed for the random number generator to reconstruct a certain path. You still wouldn't be enumerating all possible paths, but I guess that's probably not necessary for your application.

Comment: Yes, but I want to either construct one, or alter an existing one to increase variety.  There are both trivial ways to walk a two dimensional array, as well as some 'space filling' ways.  Isn't the hamiltonian complexity because of the connection constraints?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your problem. I thought that your array structure was an input defining the valid directions in which you can leave a square -- i.e. that a square is not necessarily connected to all of its neighbours. But now I understand that this is your _output_, i.e. the generated path, correct? This makes things easier because the graph is known and has a regular structure -- and, as you say, it's obvious that Hamiltonian paths exist. Still, I think that enumerating all Hamiltonian paths in this graph is probably still a hard problem.

Comment: Edited the answer now that I've understood what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This was originally a comment to Martin B's post, but it grew a bit, so I'm posting it as an "answer".

Firstly, the problem of enumerating all possible Hamiltonian Paths is quite similar to the #P complexity class --- NP's terrifying older brother. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P), as always, can explain. It is for this reason that I hope you don't really need to know *every* path, but just most. If not, well, there's still hope if you can exploit the structure of your graphs.

(Here's a fun way of looking at why enumerating all paths is really hard: Let's say you have 10 paths for the graph, and you think you're done. And evil old me comes over and says "well, prove to me that there isn't an 11th path". Having an answer that could both convince me and not take a while to demonstrate --- that would be pretty impressive! Proving that there doesn't exist *any* path is co-NP, and that's also quite hard. Proving that there only exists a certain number, that sounds very hard. Its late here, so I'm a bit fuzzy-headed, but so far I think everything I've said is correct.)

Anyways, my google-fu seems particularly weak on this subject, which is surprising, so I don't have a cold answer for you, but I have some hints?

- Firstly, if each node has at most 2 outgoing edges, then the number of edges are linear in the number of vertices, and I'm pretty sure that that means its a "sparse" graph, which are typically happier to deal with. But Hamiltonian path is exponential in the number of edges, so there's no really easy way out. :)
- Secondly, if the structure of your graph lends itself to this, it may be possible to break the problem up into smaller chunks. [Min-cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-cut) and [strongly-connected-components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) come to mind. The basic idea would be, ideally, finding that your big graph is in fact, really, 4 smaller graphs with just a **few** connecting edges between the smaller graphs. Running your HamPath algorithm on those smaller chunks would be considerably faster, and the hope would be that it would be somewhat easy to piece together the sub-graph-paths into the whole-graph-paths. Coincidentally, these are great tongue-twisters. The downside is that these algorithms are a bit difficult to implement, and will require a lot of thought and care to use properly (in the combining of the HamPaths). Furthermore, if your graphs are in fact quite thoroughly connected, this whole paragraph was for naught! :)

So those were just a few ideas. If there is any other aspect of your graph (a particular starting point is required, or a particular ending point, or additional rules about what node can connect to which), it may be quite helpful! The border between NP-complete problems and P (fast) algorithms is often quite thin.

Hope this helps, -Agor.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a trivial path through the grid, then randomly select locations on the board (using the input seed to seed the random number generator) and perform "switches" on the path where possible.   e.g.:

```
------  to:    --\/--
------         --/\--
```

With enough switches you should get a random-looking path.

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely enough, I spent an undergrad summer in my Math degree studying this problem as well as coming up with algorithms to address it. First I will comment on the other answers.

Martin B: Correctly identified this as a Hamiltonian path problem. However, if the graph is a regular grid (as you two discussed in the comments) then a Hamiltonian path can trivially be found (snaking row-major order for example.)

agnorest: Correctly talked about the Hamiltonian path problem being in a class of hard problems. agnorest also alluded to possibly exploiting the graph structure, which funny enough, is trivial in the case of a regular grid.

I will now continue the discussion by elaborating on what I *think* you are trying to achieve. As you mentioned in the comments, it is trivial to find certain classes of "space-filling" non intersecting "walks" on a regular lattice/grid. However, it seems you are not satisfied only with these and would like to find an algorithm that finds "interesting" walks that cover your grid at random. But before I explore that possibility, I'd like to point out that the "non-intersecting" property of these walks is extremely important and what causes the difficulties of enumerating them.

In fact, the thing that I studied in my summer internship is called the [Self Avoiding Walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk). Surprisingly, the study of SAWs (self avoiding walks) is very important to a few sub-domains of modeling in physics (and was a key ingredient to the [Manhattan project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_Project)!) The algorithm you gave in your question is actually a variant on an algorithm known as the "growth" algorithm or Rosenbluth's algorithm (named after non other than [Marshal Rosenbluth](https://www.atomicheritage.org/profile/marshall-rosenbluth)). More details on both the general version of this algorithm (used to estimate statistics on SAWs) as well as their relation to physics can be readily found in literature like this [thesis](https://yorkspace.library.yorku.ca/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10315/30743/Tabrizi_Mandana_2015_Masters.pdf?sequence=2).

SAWs in 2 dimensions are notoriously hard to study. Very few theoretical results are known about SAWs in 2 dimensions. Oddly enough, in higher than 3 dimensions you can say that most properties of SAWs are known theoretically, such as their growth constant. **Suffice it to say, SAWs in 2 dimensions are very interesting things!**

Reigning in this discussion to talk about your problem at hand, you are probably finding that your implementation of the growth algorithm gets "cut off" quite frequently and can not expand to fill the whole of your lattice. In this case, it is more appropriate to view your problem as a Hamiltonian Path problem. My approach to finding interesting Hamiltonian paths would be to formulate the problem as an Integer Linear Program, and add fix random edges to be used in the ILP. The fixing of random edges would give randomness to the generation process, and the ILP portion would efficiently compute whether certain configurations are feasible and if they are would return a solution.

### The Code

The following code implements the Hamiltonian path or cycle problem for arbitrary initial conditions. It implements it on a regular 2D lattice with 4-connectivity. The formulation follows the standard sub-tour elimination ILP Lagrangian. The sub-tours are eliminated lazily, meaning there can be potentially many iterations required.

You could augment this to satisfy random or otherwise initial conditions that you deem "interesting" for your problem. If the initial conditions are infeasible it terminates early and prints this.

This code depends on [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) and [PuLP](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp).

```
"""
Hamiltonian path formulated as ILP, solved using PuLP, adapted from 

https://projects.coin-or.org/PuLP/browser/trunk/examples/Sudoku1.py

Authors: ldog
"""

# Import PuLP modeler functions
from pulp import *

# Solve for Hamiltonian path or cycle
solve_type = 'cycle'

# Define grid size
N = 10

# If solving for path a start and end must be specified
if solve_type == 'path':
    start_vertex = (0,0)
    end_vertex = (5,5)

# Assuming 4-connectivity (up, down, left, right)
Edges = ["up", "down", "left", "right"]
Sequence = [ i for i in range(N) ]

# The Rows and Cols sequences follow this form, Vals will be which edge is used
Vals = Edges
Rows = Sequence
Cols = Sequence

# The prob variable is created to contain the problem data        
prob = LpProblem("Hamiltonian Path Problem",LpMinimize)

# The problem variables are created
choices = LpVariable.dicts("Choice",(Vals,Rows,Cols),0,1,LpInteger)

# The arbitrary objective function is added
prob += 0, "Arbitrary Objective Function"

# A constraint ensuring that exactly two edges per node are used 
# (a requirement for the solution to be a walk or path.)
for r in Rows:
    for c in Cols:
        if solve_type == 'cycle':
            prob += lpSum([choices[v][r][c] for v in Vals ]) == 2, ""
        elif solve_type == 'path':
            if (r,c) == end_vertex or (r,c) == start_vertex:
                prob += lpSum([choices[v][r][c] for v in Vals]) == 1, ""
            else:
                prob += lpSum([choices[v][r][c] for v in Vals]) == 2, ""

# A constraint ensuring that edges between adjacent nodes agree
for r in Rows:
    for c in Cols:
        #The up direction
        if r > 0:
            prob += choices["up"][r][c] == choices["down"][r-1][c],""
        #The down direction
        if r < N-1:
            prob += choices["down"][r][c] == choices["up"][r+1][c],""
        #The left direction
        if c > 0:
            prob += choices["left"][r][c] == choices["right"][r][c-1],""
        #The right direction
        if c < N-1:
            prob += choices["right"][r][c] == choices["left"][r][c+1],""

# Ensure boundaries are not used
for c in Cols:
    prob += choices["up"][0][c] == 0,""
    prob += choices["down"][N-1][c] == 0,""
for r in Rows:
    prob += choices["left"][r][0] == 0,""
    prob += choices["right"][r][N-1] == 0,""

# Random conditions can be specified to give "interesting" paths or cycles 
# that have this condition.
# In the simplest case, just specify one node with fixed edges used.
prob += choices["down"][2][2] == 1,""
prob += choices["up"][2][2] == 1,""

# Keep solving while the smallest cycle is not the whole thing
while True:
    # The problem is solved using PuLP's choice of Solver
    prob.solve()

    # The status of the solution is printed to the screen
    status = LpStatus[prob.status]
    print "Status:", status
    if status == 'Infeasible':
        print 'The set of conditions imposed are impossible to solve for. Change the conditions.'
        break

    import networkx as nx
    g = nx.Graph()
    g.add_nodes_from([i for i in range(N*N)])

    for r in Rows:
        for c in Cols:
            if value(choices['up'][r][c])  == 1:
                nr = r - 1
                nc = c
                g.add_edge(r*N+c,nr*N+nc)
            if value(choices['down'][r][c])  == 1:
                nr = r + 1
                nc = c
                g.add_edge(r*N+c,nr*N+nc)
            if value(choices['left'][r][c])  == 1:
                nr = r
                nc = c - 1
                g.add_edge(r*N+c,nr*N+nc)
            if value(choices['right'][r][c])  == 1:
                nr = r
                nc = c + 1
                g.add_edge(r*N+c,nr*N+nc)

    # Get connected components sorted by length
    cc = sorted(nx.connected_components(g), key = len)

    # For the shortest, add the remove cycle condition
    def ngb(idx,v):
        r = idx/N
        c = idx%N
        if v == 'up':
            nr = r - 1
            nc = c
        if v == 'down':
            nr = r + 1
            nc = c
        if v == 'left':
            nr = r 
            nc = c - 1
        if v == 'right':
            nr = r 
            nc = c + 1
        return nr*N+c

    prob += lpSum([choices[v][idx/N][idx%N] for v in Vals for idx in cc[0] if ngb(idx,v) in cc[0] ]) \
            <= 2*(len(cc[0]))-1,  ""

    # Pretty print the solution
    if len(cc[0]) == N*N:
        print ''
        print '***************************'
        print ' This is the final solution'
        print '***************************'
    for r in Rows:
        s = ""
        for c in Cols:
            if value(choices['up'][r][c])  == 1:
                s += " | "
            else:
                s += "   "
        print s
        s = ""
        for c in Cols:
            if value(choices['left'][r][c])  == 1:
                s += "-"
            else:
                s += " "
            s += "X"
            if value(choices['right'][r][c])  == 1:
                s += "-"
            else:
                s += " "
        print s
        s = ""
        for c in Cols:
            if value(choices['down'][r][c])  == 1:
                s += " | "
            else:
                s += "   "
        print s

    if len(cc[0]) != N*N:
        print 'Press key to continue to next iteration (which eliminates a suboptimal subtour) ...'
    elif len(cc[0]) == N*N:
        print 'Press key to terminate'
    raw_input()

    if len(cc[0]) == N*N:
        break
```