# algorithm for hexagon structure

Tags: java, algorithm, search

Supposed I have this data structure:

[image: Hexagon structure]

I am using a hash map to represent the data structure:

```
 HashMap<Point, Tile> board;
```

Where Point class is just consisting of int x and int y which is used to represent the coordinate in the data structure above.

```
Point(int x, int y);
```

In Tile class, every tile has an animal token on top. Such that:

```
Tile(Habitat habitat, Animal animalToken);
```

My aim is to calculate the score according to the animal tokens placed on top of the tiles.

This [link](https://cascadiagame.github.io/) has the rules for scoring for each animal.

What I've tried is completely mess, which always end up with 100+ of codes just to calculate a score for one specific animal. Is there any algorithm/searching algorithm I should know about to make my life easier?

PS: I have little knowledge on graph structure.

Edit:

```
private static ArrayList<Tile> adjacentAvailableTile(Point point)
{
    return adjacentAvailableTile(adjacentAvailablePoints(point));
}


private static ArrayList<Tile> adjacentAvailableTile(ArrayList<Point> points)
{
    ArrayList<Tile> availableTiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Point point : points)
    {
        Tile tile = board.get(point);
        availableTiles.add(tile);
    }
    return availableTiles;
}


private static ArrayList<Point> adjacentAvailablePoints(Point originPoint)
{
    Point[] sixAdjacentPoint = new Point[6];
    int i = 0;
    for (Position pos : Position.values())      //loop through enum Position
    {
        //sixAdjacentPoint now has the adjacent points of the given point
        sixAdjacentPoint[i++] = getPoint(originPoint, pos);
    }

    ArrayList<Point> availablePoint = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Point point : sixAdjacentPoint)
    {
        if (board.containsKey(point))
            availablePoint.add(point);
    }
    return availablePoint;
}
```

I now can find adjacent tiles from a given point.

Comment: some of the logic seems pretty complex, but I suspect you can break it down in smaller functions. For instance, a function that returns all adjacent tiles from a given tile will probably be very helpful. Without the code you've written, it is hard to say what is wrong/could be improved with it though

Comment: That's a good suggestion. The codes are way too long to be reviewed. I was hoping to start again from scratch and try to look in another way.

Comment: I think, having a `GetAdjacentTiles` function should be enough to solve the bear, Hawk and Fox rules. For the Salmon, you will need something looking like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506150/longest-path-on-a-grid-without-revisiting-grid-cells). And for the Elk, I guess some function like `NumberOfElkInThisDirection` which walks through one of the 6 directions from a tile, and counts the number of elks in a row should do the trick

Comment: @FlorentMonin if I have an arrayList `ArrayList<Point> bear;` which contains the point of all bears in the board. Is this going to help?

Comment: for the bears, I think what you can do is run an algorithm to find the connected components (so you number each "group of bear") and then, for each group, if it has exactly 2 members, then it's a pair, otherwise it isn't. I think that should work

Comment: Not directly related: Why using a `HashMap` instead of an 2D array (you already have x,y coordinates in your image)) which is a wildly used way to store such a hex-raster?
here a nice resource for hex-grid algorithms and data-structures https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Comment: @MrSmith42 How would you implement this in 2D array? The coordinate in this data structure has negative coordinate, which I'm not sure of how to implement in 2D array..

Comment: @st3ems By adding an offset all coordinates become positive.

Comment: @MrSmith42 that makes sense. But a 2D array would take up more memory than I intended to use? I also have to define the size of the 2D array, which I'm not sure of since the user can place a tile at any position..