# Finding path from cell x to cell y in a grid so that all cells are parsed once

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, graph-algorithm

I am trying to code an algorithm so that it can start from any "start" cell of a grid ( eg.cell no. 4 in the pic) and parse through each cell of a grid once. The grid can be of any size 3x3, 4x4, 8x8 etc.

The following codes generates such paths. And works fine for many cells in 8x8 grid. But for many cells, it takes forever to search a path.

I was wondering if there is some better solution that can be referenced, so that the solution can be optimized.

```
package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var rand_Num;


    public var node0_Mc:MovieClip ,node1_Mc:MovieClip,node2_Mc:MovieClip,node3_Mc:MovieClip,node4_Mc:MovieClip,node5_Mc:MovieClip,node6_Mc:MovieClip,node7_Mc:MovieClip,node8_Mc:MovieClip,node9_Mc:MovieClip,
    node10_Mc:MovieClip,node11_Mc:MovieClip,node12_Mc:MovieClip,node13_Mc:MovieClip,node14_Mc:MovieClip,node15_Mc:MovieClip,node16_Mc:MovieClip,node17_Mc:MovieClip,node18_Mc:MovieClip,node19_Mc:MovieClip,
    node20_Mc:MovieClip,node21_Mc:MovieClip,node22_Mc:MovieClip,node23_Mc:MovieClip,node24_Mc:MovieClip,node25_Mc:MovieClip,node26_Mc:MovieClip,node27_Mc:MovieClip,node28_Mc:MovieClip,node29_Mc:MovieClip,
    node30_Mc:MovieClip,node31_Mc:MovieClip,node32_Mc:MovieClip,node33_Mc:MovieClip,node34_Mc:MovieClip,node35_Mc:MovieClip,node36_Mc:MovieClip,node37_Mc:MovieClip,node38_Mc:MovieClip,node39_Mc:MovieClip,
    node40_Mc:MovieClip,node41_Mc:MovieClip,node42_Mc:MovieClip,node43_Mc:MovieClip,node44_Mc:MovieClip,node45_Mc:MovieClip,node46_Mc:MovieClip,node47_Mc:MovieClip,node48_Mc:MovieClip,node49_Mc:MovieClip,
    node50_Mc:MovieClip,node51_Mc:MovieClip,node52_Mc:MovieClip,node53_Mc:MovieClip,node54_Mc:MovieClip,node55_Mc:MovieClip,node56_Mc:MovieClip,node57_Mc:MovieClip,node58_Mc:MovieClip,node59_Mc:MovieClip,
    node60_Mc:MovieClip, node61_Mc:MovieClip, node62_Mc:MovieClip, node63_Mc:MovieClip;
    public const NUM_COLS:Number = 8;
    // 3 ;// 4 ;
    public const NUM_ROWS:Number = 8;// 3 ;// 4 ;



    var chain_Arr:Array = [];
    var blockIndex_Arr:Array = [];
    var nodearr:Array;

    var adjacentNodeArray_Arr:Array = [];
    var parsedNodeIndex_Arr:Array = [];
    var validNextAdjacentNodeIndexArray_Arr:Array = [];
    var validPreviousAdjacentNodeIndexArray_Arr:Array = [];
    var savePair_Arr:Array = [];
    var countChain_Num:Number = 0;
    var saveParent_Arr:Array = [];

    public function Main()
    {
        // constructor code
        nodearr = [node0_Mc,node1_Mc,node2_Mc,node3_Mc,node4_Mc,node5_Mc,node6_Mc,node7_Mc,node8_Mc,node9_Mc,node10_Mc,node11_Mc,node12_Mc,node13_Mc,node14_Mc,node15_Mc,node16_Mc,node17_Mc,node18_Mc,node19_Mc,node20_Mc,node21_Mc,node22_Mc,node23_Mc,node24_Mc,node25_Mc,node26_Mc,node27_Mc,node28_Mc,node29_Mc,node30_Mc,node31_Mc,node32_Mc,node33_Mc,node34_Mc,node35_Mc,node36_Mc,node37_Mc,node38_Mc,node39_Mc,node40_Mc,node41_Mc,node42_Mc,node43_Mc,node44_Mc,node45_Mc,node46_Mc,node47_Mc,node48_Mc,node49_Mc,node50_Mc,node51_Mc,node52_Mc,node53_Mc,node54_Mc,node55_Mc,node56_Mc,node57_Mc,node58_Mc,node59_Mc,node60_Mc,node61_Mc,node62_Mc,node63_Mc];

        var possibleAdjacentNodeIndex_Arr:Array = [];

        initValidNextAdjacentNodeIndexArray();
        initValidPreviousAdjacentNodeIndexArray();

        savePair_Arr = [];

        var startIndex_num:Number = 45;// 0 ;

        rand_Num = 62;// randomRange(10, (NUM_COLS * NUM_ROWS) - 1); 
        getAllChainsFromParamNodeIndexParamParentChain(startIndex_num,[startIndex_num]);


    }

    function initValidNextAdjacentNodeIndexArray():void
    {
        for (var index_num = 0; index_num < NUM_COLS*NUM_ROWS; index_num++)
        {
            validNextAdjacentNodeIndexArray_Arr[index_num] = getValidNodeIndexArrayAdjacentToParamNodeIndex(index_num);
            //trace(validNextAdjacentNodeIndexArray_Arr[index_num]);
        }
    }

    function initValidPreviousAdjacentNodeIndexArray():void
    {
        for (var index_num = 0; index_num < NUM_COLS*NUM_ROWS; index_num++)
        {
            validPreviousAdjacentNodeIndexArray_Arr[index_num] = getValidNodeIndexArrayAdjacentToParamNodeIndex(index_num);
            //trace(validNextAdjacentNodeIndexArray_Arr[index_num]);
        }
    }

    //function getAllChainsFromParamNodeIndexParamParentChain(  path_arr:Array,index_param_num:Number ):void 

    function getAllChainsFromParamNodeIndexParamParentChain(  index_param_num:Number, parent_arr:Array ):void
    {
        var i;

        if ( countChain_Num > 15 )
        {
            return;
        }


        reinitPath();

        var adjacent_arr = getValidNodeIndexArrayAdjacentToParamNodeIndex(index_param_num);

        for (i = 0; i < adjacent_arr.length; i++)
        {



            reinitPath();
            if ( ( checkRepeat(chain_Arr)) )
            {

                continue;
            }


            chain_Arr.push(adjacent_arr[i]);
            //trace("chain starts from", chain_Arr);


            var nodeIndex_num:Number = adjacent_arr[i];
            var nodeIndexExist_num = 0;
            var parentNode_num:Number = parent_arr[parent_arr.length - 1];

            var bool:Boolean;
            while ( isNaN(nodeIndex_num) == false)
            {

                //var childNodeIndex_num = manageValidAdjacentIndexArray(parent_arr[parent_arr.length-1], parentNode_num , nodeIndex_num );
                var childNodeIndex_num = manageValidAdjacentIndexArray(adjacent_arr[i],parentNode_num,nodeIndex_num);
                //var childNodeIndex_num = manageValidAdjacentIndexArray(parentNode_num, parentNode_num , nodeIndex_num );
                parentNode_num = nodeIndex_num;
                nodeIndex_num = childNodeIndex_num;

                if ( ( checkRepeat(chain_Arr)) )
                {

                    break;
                }


                if ( isNaN(nodeIndex_num) == false)
                {
                    chain_Arr.push(nodeIndex_num);
                }


            }


            if (chain_Arr.length > NUM_COLS * NUM_ROWS - 1)
            {


                //if ( !( checkRepeat(chain_Arr)) )
                {
                    trace(chain_Arr);
                    saveParent_Arr[saveParent_Arr.length ] = new Array();
                    for (var k = 0; k < rand_Num; k++)
                    {
                        saveParent_Arr[saveParent_Arr.length - 1].push(  chain_Arr[k]);
                    }

                    countChain_Num++;
                }



            }


        };




        for (i = 0; i < adjacent_arr.length; i++)
        {




            var arr2:Array = parent_arr.slice();

            arr2.push(adjacent_arr[i]);

            getAllChainsFromParamNodeIndexParamParentChain(   adjacent_arr[i], arr2 );
        }

        function reinitPath():void
        {
            chain_Arr = [];

            chain_Arr = chain_Arr.concat(parent_arr);
        }


    }

    private function checkRepeat(chain_arr:Array):Boolean
    {
        var bool:Boolean;
        var num = rand_Num;
        if (chain_arr.length >= num - 1)
        {


            for (var i = 0; i < saveParent_Arr.length; i++)
            {
                //trace( saveParent_Arr[i][0], saveParent_Arr[i][1]);
                if (saveParent_Arr[i] != undefined)
                {
                    var z = 0;
                    for (var j = 0; j < num; j++)
                    {
                        if (saveParent_Arr[i][j] == chain_arr[j])
                        {
                            z++;
                            if ( z >= num)
                            {
                                bool = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (bool)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }

        }



        return bool;


    }
    function randomRange( minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number
    {
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
    }

    function randomizeArray(arr:Array ):void
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            var random = randomRange(0,arr.length - 1);
            var temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[random];
            arr[random] = temp;
        }

    }


    //will send NaN if no valid adjacent index array is possible
    private function manageValidAdjacentIndexArray(chainStartIndex_num:Number, parentNodeIndex_param_num:Number, nodeIndex_num:Number):Number
    {
        var num_nan:Number;
        var ret_num:Number;
        var j;
        //var tot:Number = validNextAdjacentNodeIndexArray_Arr[nodeIndex_num].length ;

        j = 0;
        var arr:Array = validNextAdjacentNodeIndexArray_Arr[nodeIndex_num];// getValidNodeIndexArrayAdjacentToParamNodeIndex(nodeIndex_num) ;

        randomizeArray(arr);

        while (arr.length > 0 )// && isNaN(ret_num))
        {

            ret_num = arr[j];//validNextAdjacentNodeIndexArray_Arr[nodeIndex_num][j] ;

            //if this index is present in chain then remove it off 
            if (chain_Arr.indexOf(ret_num) >= 0)
            {
                //j++ ;
                ret_num = num_nan;
            }


            j++;

            if ( j >= arr.length )
            {
                ret_num = num_nan;
                break;
            }


        }


        return ret_num;
    }



    private function getValidAdjacentIndexToParamNodeIndex(nodeIndex_param_num:Number):Number
    {
        var adjacentNode_arr:Array = [];
        var adjacentRow_arr:Array = [];
        var adjacentCol_arr:Array = [];

        var allIndex_arr:Array = [];

        var r:Number;
        var c:Number;

        var row_num:Number = int(nodeIndex_param_num / NUM_COLS);
        var col_num:Number = (nodeIndex_param_num % NUM_COLS);

        allIndex_arr = getAllAdjacentNodeIndexArray(row_num,col_num);

        validateIndices(allIndex_arr);

        var ret_num:Number;
        ret_num = allIndex_arr[0];
        return ret_num;

    }



    function getValidNodeIndexArrayAdjacentToParamNodeIndex(nodeIndex_param_num:Number ):Array
    {
        var adjacentNode_arr = [];

        for (var positionId_num = 0; positionId_num < 8; positionId_num++)
        {
            var num:Number = getNodeIndexAtParamPositionIdOfParamIndex(positionId_num,nodeIndex_param_num);

            if (isNaN(num))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                adjacentNode_arr.push(num);
            }
        }

        return adjacentNode_arr;
    }



    private function getAllAdjacentNodeIndexArray(row_num:Number, col_num:Number,within_arr:Array=null):Array
    {

        var num:Number;
        var index_arr:Array = [num,num,num,num,num,num,num,num];
        var r:Number;
        var c:Number;

        if ( row_num > 0 )
        {
            r = row_num - 1;
            c = col_num;
            index_arr[0] = r * NUM_COLS + c;

        }


        if ( col_num < NUM_COLS-1)
        {
            r = row_num;
            c = col_num + 1;
            index_arr[1] = r * NUM_COLS + c;
        }


        if ( row_num < NUM_ROWS-1)
        {
            r = row_num + 1;
            c = col_num;
            index_arr[2] = r * NUM_COLS + c;

        }

        if ( col_num > 0 )
        {
            r = row_num;
            c = col_num - 1;
            index_arr[3] = r * NUM_COLS + c;
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////


        if ( row_num  > 0 && col_num > 0)
        {
            r = row_num - 1;
            c = col_num - 1;
            index_arr[4] = r * NUM_COLS + c;
        }

        if ( row_num > 0 && col_num < NUM_COLS-1)
        {
            r = row_num - 1;
            c = col_num + 1;
            index_arr[5] = r * NUM_COLS + c;
        }

        if ( row_num < NUM_ROWS-1 && col_num < NUM_COLS-1)
        {
            r = row_num + 1;
            c = col_num + 1;
            index_arr[6] = r * NUM_COLS + c;
        }

        if ( row_num < NUM_ROWS-1 && col_num > 0 )
        {
            r = row_num + 1;
            c = col_num - 1;
            index_arr[7] = r * NUM_COLS + c;
        }



        return index_arr;

    }

    //the adjacent node must be present in within_arr, which we splice, one time for variation 
    function getNodeIndexAtParamPositionIdOfParamIndex( n:Number , nodeIndex_param_num:Number):Number
    {
        var adjacentNode_arr:Array = [];
        var adjacentRow_arr:Array = [];
        var adjacentCol_arr:Array = [];

        var index_arr:Array = [];

        var r:Number;
        var c:Number;
        var index_num:Number;
        var row_num:Number = int(nodeIndex_param_num / NUM_COLS);
        var col_num:Number = (nodeIndex_param_num % NUM_COLS);

        index_arr = getAllAdjacentNodeIndexArray(row_num,col_num);

        validateIndices(index_arr);

        var ret_num:Number;
        ret_num = index_arr[n];
        return ret_num;

    }

    private function validateIndices(index_arr:Array):void
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < index_arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (chain_Arr.indexOf(index_arr[i]) == -1)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                var num:Number;
                index_arr[i] = num;//pushing NaN
            }
        }
    }








}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill 2D grid with single path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898884/fill-2d-grid-with-single-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Hamiltonian path problem. It's NP complete and afaik there is still no efficient solution.

check this out: [hamilton paths in grid graphs](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~itai/publications/Algorithms/Hamilton-paths.pdf) (pdf)

short randomized algorithm explanation: [Princeton Hamiltonian path problem](https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Hamiltonian_path_problem.html)

or wikipedia: [Hamiltonian path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem)

edit:

I did some more research and for your special case of strongly connected square grids (nxn chessboards) a variation of the warndoffs rule for finding a knights tour might give you a solution in near linear time. See here: [A method for finding hamiltonian paths and knight tours](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~pohl/Spring04/warns.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: you are right, this is a grid graph and i updated my references. It's still proven to be NP complete according to the paper i linked.

Comment: Grid graphs can have edges missing from the grid.

Comment: i did some more research and edited my answer with a reference for nxn grids (chessboards)