# Get Contiguous Faces In a Mesh

Tags: algorithm, mesh, traversal

I am looking for an algorithm to find all (or maximum no of) contiguous faces of a continuous mesh. The faces should be ordered in an array in such a way that each face is preceded by a face linked to it on the mesh. The ultimate goal is to have a single such array. Is it possible even in theory? If not what's the best way to maximize the count of faces in the array?

In [this (rather naive) implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlTZN.gif) the selection point traverses clockwise covering end vertex of the available edge of the last face covered. But this quickly gets into a dead-end. I also tried both the ends of the edge, or all the available vertices of the face, but sooner or later each one reaches a face with no connections to un-selected faces.

Edit:

It's a triangulated mesh, i.e. each face has exactly three vertices. And the requirement is to have a set of minimum no of arrays (ideally one) covering all the connected faces of the mesh.

Comment: how are you representing the mesh? also how do you define an dis-contiguity? ideally I presume the mesh is well formed and there are no "holes". Wouldn't every face be reachable from every other face?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hard problem (the [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) in a planar graph (specifically, the dual of the input graph)), but you may have get good results with a local search method. There's a simple one due to Angluin and Valiant (https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000(79)90045-X) and a more complicated effort by Frieze (https://doi.org/10.1002/rsa.20542). These algorithms are proved in theory to work on random graphs only, but graphs without adversarial construction are often amenable too.

Comment: I was thinking of the problem in this terms too, although I don't know if there is some topological approach that may simplify it. Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) it is said that 4-connected planar graphs always have a Hamiltonian path and it can be computed in linear time, so I suppose it can always be done for closed meshes of quads. Which I'm not sure if is too surprising. Also this is assuming that the mesh is "well-formed" (manifold), otherwise the graph wouldn't have to be planar I think?

Comment: @jdehesa Sure. Those algorithms work on general graphs.

Comment: This (Angluin and Valiant) looks very promising. I need some time to understand and implement it, though. Will share the result on this thread when I have made some progress with the implementation.

Comment: I would really appreciate anyone with acess to the cited sources writtingva simple explaination of each.

Comment: @AndrewMicallef I implemented A--V for another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15904295/2144669

Comment: @AndrewMicallef the short version is: extend the path randomly, if it cycles back on itself then delete one of the cycle edges incident to the degree-3 vertex and then continue at the other end.