# Is there an algorithm to create a Smart Snake to Fill Entire Map if Possible Without Colliding to either part of its Body or Wall

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, flood-fill

### Please help me by **refering the Algorithm Name** or if you have any good **source code to solve the problem**

---

To understand the problem,

**Here's some input in JSON Format Correspond with Their Initial Map Picture**

{"wallX":[0,2],"wallY":[0,2],"startX":0,"startY":1,"maxX":3,"maxY":3}

[image]

{"wallX":[],"wallY":[],"startX":1,"startY":4,"maxX":6,"maxY":6}

[image]

**The Rules**

1. 99 represent the wall. X&Y of wall[index] is represent by wallX[index] and wallY[index].
2. 01 represent the starting point of the Snake. X&Y of 01 is represent by startX and startY
3. maxX represent the column of the 2D array while maxY represent the row of the 2d array. *Both maxX and maxY <= 9*
4. On The initial 2-D Array / Map, any tile which is not 01 or 99 will be Tile 00.
5. Snake can only Move to 00
6. Snake move 4 ways[left,top,right,bottom]

**The input** of the program is those JSON format.

**The output** of the program should be :

1. 2-Dimension Array consist of 99 and/or (01 to 0X) with no 00 Tiles left which represent the map is solved
2. Initial 2-D Array which represent there is no more possible move left but there is at least 1 of 00

**Here's Some other Input Correspond with Their output's 2D Array picture**

{"wallX":[0,0,1,2,3,4,5],"wallY":[0,4,5,1,1,1,4],"startX":0,"startY":3,"maxX":6,"maxY":8}

[image]

{"wallX":[0,1],"wallY":[0,1],"startX":0,"startY":1,"maxX":2,"maxY":2}

[image: ""]

{"wallX":[0,2],"wallY":[0,2],"startX":1,"startY":1,"maxX":3,"maxY":3}

[image]

---

I have made my own source code to solve this problem, but i want to find the algorithm so i can study more on how to actually deal with this/related algorithm/problem.

1. I tried to search on google, with keyword such as "Fill" but most result showing me [Flood-Fill-Algorithm]. Most Flood Fill that i read, can't be applied here since The Snake or [LastNumber] have to be Adjacent to [LastNumber+1].
2. I also tried to find about Pathing, but it seems PathFinding works if there is Start and Destination, but this problem doesn't seem have any clear Destination.

*Please correct me if im wrong about these ^*

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This is a hard problem. It's equivalent to finding a Hamiltonian cycle in a graph (cells are vertices; adjacent cells have an edge). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem

Comment: @Dave The fact that problem X can be specified as a special case of NP-complete problem Y does not mean that X is NP-complete.  So the problem of finding Hamiltonian cycles in rectangular grids with some omitted nodes might be polynomial even though the same problem for general graphs is NP-complete.

Comment: For this case, see https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2012/475087/ showing some success for solving this kind of problem for some rectangular shapes.  Given that that is published research and a simple version of the general problem, it suggests that the problem is hard.  But it may still be possible.  At the least, the necessary test "even number of black/white squares on a checkerboard pattern" can let many arrangement of walls be recognized quickly as impossible.

Comment: I suspect Hamilton path in arbitrarily walled grid graphs is hard, but Angluin--Valiant may be a decent heuristic in practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898884/fill-2d-grid-with-single-path/15904295#15904295

Comment: NB: it is strange to see a property named "maxX" when it does not provide the maximum value for X, but one more -- since your examples show a coordinate system is zero-based. Better names would be "sizeX" or "endX".

Comment: @btilly It's NP for subgraphs of a lattice or square grid graph (according to the wikipedia article)